# Using AutoFac BootStrapper?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, autofac

I am attempting to translate a WPF example of IOC using StructureMap into Silverlight using AutoFac

This is proving to be very difficult

I have got a static BootStrapper class defined

```
public class BootStrapper
{
  public static IContainer BaseContainer { get; private set; }

  public static FlexContractStructureViewModel FlexContractStructureViewModel()
  {
      return BaseContainer.Resolve<FlexContractStructureViewModel>();
  }

  public static void Build()
  {
      if (BaseContainer == null)
      {
          var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
          builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes();

          BaseContainer = builder.Build();
      }
  }

  static BootStrapper()
  {

  }

}
```

This is initialised in the Application_Startup in App.xaml.cs

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  BootStrapper.Build();

  this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}
```

I have set the DataContext of one of my views to use my BootStrapper

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=FlexContractStructureViewModel, 
              Source={StaticResource classes:BootStrapper}}"
```

But I get the error Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key classes:BootStrapper

The book I am using states to make a change to the App.xaml to add

But I cant do that because ObjectDataProvider is not recognised

I have tried the equivalent below with no luck

```
<bs:BootStrapper xmlns:bs="clr-namespace:SLDashboard2.Classes" x:Key="BootStrapper"/>
```

I think this may be related to having BootStrapper static?  But I dont want to be constantly creating new Containers

Can someone help please?

Paul

Comment: Wait what, why are you doing static datacontext through the bootstrapper? You don't want to define all your viewmodels as static in your IoC?

Comment: If I dont make it static I thought that would mean that I would constantly be searching assemblies all the time with AutoFac?  Sounds like I am wrong though?

Comment: Wrong. Shouldn't you be registering all your ViewModels in your IoC? and then you inject them to your constructors. They should never be static and I don't usually use static resources as my datacontext in my view.

Comment: ok great that worked thanks stopped it from static now the simple View Models are being injected.  I initially used Simple MVVM which uses MEF to inject domain services, I cant get that to work but I am going to raise a new question for that

Comment: Kk, I'll post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong. Shouldn't you be registering all your ViewModels in your IoC? and then you inject them to your constructors. They should never be static and I don't usually use static resources as my datacontext in my view